# cakephp 2.0 jpgraph

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, jpgraph

I have had a difficult time getting jpgraph to work with cakephp.  I have a Controller called "Graphs" and all it does is display the view.  View/Graphs/index.ctp is very simple:

```
echo "This is an image of my report";
echo "<img src='/<projectbase>/reports/index'></img>";
```

which I believe tries to get the information from the ReportsController and then its view called index.  I then have a ReportsController:

```
<?php
class ReportsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Reports';
    function index() {
        $this->layout='ajax';
    }
}
```

which just calls the index view in Reports and this returns ajax information.  I then have the View/Reports/index.ctp:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'jpgraph/jpgraph');
App::import('Vendor', 'jpgraph/jpgraph_line');

// Some data
$ydata = array(11,3,8,12,5,1,9,13,5,7);

// Create the graph. These two calls are always required
$graph = new Graph(350,250);
$graph->SetScale('textlin');

// Create the linear plot
$lineplot=new LinePlot($ydata);
$lineplot->SetColor('blue');

// Add the plot to the graph
$graph->Add($lineplot);

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke();
```

Now based on [this link](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/cguyer/2007/12/26/using-jpgraph) the View/Graphs/index.ctp has an image link that calls the View/Reports/index.ctp and tells it to return the jpgraph that I want.  When I run this code, I get an error "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html".  If I go to the link directly (localhost//reports/index) it spits out a lot of funky characters, and PNG is near the beginning.  I believe this is binary that was generated from the jpgraph stuff so I believe SOMETHING is being generated but it isnt being rendered correctly, nor brought into the View/Graps/index.ctp correctly.

I feel like unless I am missing something really small, I stole this essentially verbatim from the link in the question so its annoying it isnt working.  Am I missing something?  Is there an easier way to plot in cakephp?

My theory on this is that there is something weird about how I am grabbing the data from the view and also how the App::Vendor() call is working in cake php.  When I tell an image to look outside the cakephp structure for the jpgraph it generates it with no problem:

```
echo "<img src='/jpgraph/Examples/example0.php'></img>";
```

and when i go to this page directly it is able to generate the graph with no problem.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I believe I have come to a hack solution for using jpgraph.  The problem is with how it is streamed.  What I do is I have my Graphs Controller below:

```
<?php
class GraphsController extends AppController {
var $name = 'Graphs';

function index() {
    // call Reports view to generate new graph
    //$var = ClassRegistry::init('Reports')->index();
    //$this->set(compact('var'));
    $this->generateGraph();
}

/*
 * This function generates the grph to be displayed.  It is a little bit of a hack:
 * I save the image to a file, then in the index.ctp I extract that image.  For now,
 * that is the only way I can get jpgraph to work.
 */
function generateGraph() {
    App::import('Vendor', 'jpgraph/jpgraph');
    App::import('Vendor', 'jpgraph/jpgraph_line');

    // Some data
    $ydata = array(11,3,8,12,5,1,9,13,5,7);

    // Create the graph. These two calls are always required
    $graph = new Graph(350,250);
    $graph->SetScale('textlin');

    // Create the linear plot
    $lineplot=new LinePlot($ydata);
    $lineplot->SetColor('blue');

    // Add the plot to the graph
    $graph->Add($lineplot);

    // Get the handler to prevent the library from sending the
    // image to the browser
    $gdImgHandler = $graph->Stroke(_IMG_HANDLER);

    // Stroke image to a file

    // Default is PNG so use ".png" as suffix
    $fileName = "imagefile.png";
    $graph->img->Stream($fileName);

    // Send it back to browser
    //$graph->img->Headers();
    //$graph->img->Stream();
}
}
```

Where I call the Graphs index function which then calls the View/Graphs/index.ctp.  In the controller above I call a function generateGraph() which does exactly that and stores the image to a file in app/webroot.  Then I have the View/Graphs/index.ctp below:

```
<?php
echo "<img src='imagefile.png'></img>";
?>
```

which looks in the app/webroot directory for the image I just generated.  I know this is a hack and if anyone knows how to do this more gracefully, I am willing to try that when I get some extra time!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Cake `Vendor` structure, it's detailed [in the Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files). This will ensure you have access to the various JpGraph functions.

So, for example, put your files in `app/Vendor/jpgraph` and you can include the main JpGraph file (if it's called `jpgrah.php`) like so:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'jpgraph/jpgraph');
```

There are some tutorials for Cake 1.3 which might apply to the new 2.0 situation, [this article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/cguyer/2007/12/26/using-jpgraph) and [this one](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/15). I can't vouch for the quality of both articles, but it should give you some direction. You can consult the migration guides for [2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html) and [2.1](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-1-migration-guide.html) should any problems arise.

**EDIT:**

Regarding the incorrect content-type; you can set the content type [using the RequestHandler in Cake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html#responding-to-requests). Cake is rendering content as text/html by default, so you need to explicitly set the content-type. Use `respondAs` in your controller method.

```
$this->RequestHandler->respondAs();
```

Comment: Hi Mensch, thanks for your quick response.  I had tried those links you suggested and I still seem to be having trouble with it.  I edited the question itself to be more specific about the things I tried.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think your update might merit its own question as it concerns another, probably unrelated, problem.

Comment: I tried changing the content type by adding "var $components = array('RequestHandler');" to define the RequestHandler then calling it within my ReportsController with "$this->RequestHandler->respondAs();"  I tried all sorts of RequestHandler types (image/png, text/plain, application/json) but still no dice.  I was able to verify that the response type did change when requested.  Also, going to the ReportsController directly with the response set to image/png caused a blank image to be generated and the incorrect content type was no longer thrown.  It just renders a blank image.

Comment: JpGraph probably throws errors which corrupt the image data. Is there any error output if you set the content type back to text and remove the `$this->layout` call?

Comment: Yes it does.  It spits out "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:".  If I try going to the ReportsController directly it downloads "%PNG" followed by lots of characters which I assume is the image data.  Without the $this->layout='ajax' this file includes the full HTML header and body statements.  With the layout set to ajax it just downloads the "%PNG" followed by the funky characters.  Neither of these display the graph in the Graph View which is requesting the data.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the problem might stem from JpGraph, it might be wise to test your JpGraph code outside the Cake environment first and see if this throws any errors.

Comment: Thanks again for all your comments.  so I took the jpgraph library and put it outside of the cake directory structure.  I then put an image element in my cake view.  This way it goes searching outside of cake to create the image.  Here is the call: echo "<img src='/jpgraph/Examples/example0.php'></img>";  This call worked fine so I am still leaning towards cake as the problem.